# How to solve the Free Space Path Loss formula (Logarithms)

Tags: statistics, logarithms, computer-science

I don't have a strong mathematical understanding of logarithms so I would like some help with understanding the formula - it's a bit confusing for me as it is

1) What is the meaning of `20*logf` and `20*logd`

2) What is the significance of the `20*`

3) How would I calculate this on a calculator

[The Revision slide for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dkFP.png)

**Lp = 36.6 + (20*log10(F)) + (20 log10(D))**

Lp = free-space path loss between antennas (in dB)

F = frequency in MHz

D = path length in miles

Comment: I take them to mean $\log{f}$ and $\log{d}$

Comment: "$20 *$" means "$20 \times$" (= 20 times what follows). "20 stars" would also be eligible in this Xmas time...

Comment: Using the fact that $\log a + \log b = \log ab$, the easiest way to enter this on your calculator is to type the value of f, $*$, the value of d, $=$.  Then $\log$ (I'm not sure what base this log is supposed to be with respect to, you may have adjust) and $=$ again.  Then multiply by $20$ (and $=$ again).  Finally, add 36.6 and hit $=$.  This order will save you from any difficulties coming from calculators not always respecting order of operations in the way you expect them to.It also saves you a few keystrokes.